# C# Sometimes Getting Error "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/Article/List/TotalCount/{CompanyID}", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
        request.AddParameter("CompanyID", CompanyID, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.AddBody(filterData);
        var response = Client.Execute<GridViewCount>(request);
        if (response.Data == null)
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage); //Here I am getting Error.
```

This is the code I have written to call web api using RestSharp.

This code works fine and my Web API code works fine as well. But sometimes I get Error that "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server"

note: this is MVC project.

Comment: Please refer to this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052218/connection-that-was-expected-to-be-kept-alive-was-closed-by-the-server-in-asp-ne) for possible reasons for this error.

Answer (score 0):

That's a mistake, because you've been calling that code twice. You most likely have a static class or should you create a new instance for the object