# Why do dotnet keepalive Http connections fail on the second request with "A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server."?

Tags: .net, apache, dotnet-httpclient, keep-alive, servicepoint

I have a dotnet framework application which performs POST api requests to a remote server running Apache.  It intermittently fails with the error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

This occurs on the second request to the server when done over a keepalive TLS connection, and so occurs more frequently in production systems under heavy load and less frequently or not at all in development environments.

We have tried:

- Disabling `Expect: 100-Continue` header behaviour (`ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false`)
- Enabling TCP keep-alive (`ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive()`)

Disabling HTTP keep-alive appears to work around the issue. (`HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false`)

Is there a way to solve this without disabling http keep-alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache setting `KeepAliveTimeout` defaults to 5s of inactivity before an idle keep-alive connection will be closed. (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout)

This leads to a condition where:

1. dotnet opens a connection to apache and issues a POST
2. apache returns a 200 OK.
3. the connection is "idle" waiting for another request.
4. after 2s dotnet opens a new HttpWebRequest and calls GetRequestStream() on it ready to write the request.  Since there is an idle connection in the pool, that connection is used.
5. after 5s (`KeepAliveTimeout`), apache sends a FIN packet to close the underlying connection.
6. after (say) 30s dotnet attempts to *write* to the stream, which attempts to use the now-defunct socket and immediately fails with `The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.`

This is particularly a problem in large POST calls (say, calling a SOAP API) where forming the payload may take a nontrivial amount of time.

Possible solutions are:

1. Do not call `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` until immediately before starting to send data.
2. Disable keep-alive (`HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false`).  However that note if any other thread in your application is using keep-alive then the problem will occur (the two requests above can be in entirely different threads)
3. The most robust solution appears to be to implementing application-level retry.

Note importantly that this behaviour (of "locking a stream to a socket") only seems to occur in dotnet framework, not in dotnet 5/core.